# C# DependencyInjection AddOptions and Bind return null object

Tags: c#

i have i console application that use Dependency Injection for inject the instances in my services. I have a problem with the methods AddOptions and Bind, in my DI configuration i have this code:

```
public static IHost BuildHost()
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            //......
            ConfigureSettings<Settings>(nameof(Settings));

            //.......

            void ConfigureSettings<T>(string sectionKey) where T : class, new()
            {
                var section = context.Configuration.GetSection(sectionKey);
                //services.Configure<T>(section);  // this works fine
                services.AddOptions<T>(sectionKey).Bind(section); // this returs null Enviromets
            }
        });

    return builder.Build();
}
```

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
    "Settings": {
      "Environments": [
        {
          "EnvironmentName" : "Staging",
          "BaseUri" : "https://stage.uri.com"
        },
        {
          "EnvironmentName" : "Development",
          "BaseUri" : "https://dev.uri.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

and these are the class that i'm tryng to bind:

```
public class Settings
{
    [Required] public List<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
}

public class Environment
{
    [Required] public string EnvironmentName { get; set; }

    [Required] public string BaseUri { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when i use the commented code:

```
services.Configure<T>(section);
```

the injected IOptions value is not null and the Environmets object is populated, instead when i use the not commented code:

```
services.AddOptions<T>(sectionKey).Bind(section);
```

the injected IOptions value is not null but the Environmets object is null.

I don't understand why this happens, because inside the method Bind there is a call to:

```
optionsBuilder.Services.Configure<TOptions>(optionsBuilder.Name, config, configureBinder);
```

What am I doing wrong? Why does this happen?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The problem is due to the use of

`AddOptions<T>(sectionName)`

which is a named options, and cannot be found via IOptions but only via the use of a `.Get(sectionKey)` of an `IOptionsSnapshot` or `IOptionsMonitor` object. In the example posted by @Aleksei Petrov, the right method is actually called without passing the sectionName.

So the correct code to make it work is:

`services.AddOptions<T>().Bind(section);`

Here's a link that might help you understand:

[Andrew Lock - Named Options](https://andrewlock.net/using-multiple-instances-of-strongly-typed-settings-with-named-options-in-net-core-2-x/)

Answer (score 1):

asp.net core options binder is not working well with arrays. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#boa):

> The ConfigurationBinder.Bind supports binding arrays to objects using array indices in configuration keys.

```
public class ArrayExample
{
    public string[]? Entries { get; set; } 
}

{
  "array": {
    "entries": {
      "0": "value00",
      "1": "value10",
      "2": "value20",
      "4": "value40",
      "5": "value50"
    }
  }
}
```

I would recommend to change your settings format to Dictionary style, if you don't want to deal with custom binders and other workarounds. Something like:

```
public class Settings
{
    [Required] public IDictionary<string, Environment> Environments { get; set; }
}

public class Environment
{
    [Required] public string BaseUri { get; set; }
}

{
  "Settings": {
    "Environments": {
      "Staging": {
        "BaseUri" : "https://stage.uri.com"
      },
      "Development": {
        "BaseUri" : "https://dev.uri.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPD**:

Working demo: https://github.com/GTmAster/BindDemo.

Prints environments from setting to logger

[image: logs]

Comment: Sorry, I did the wrong test. Your solution doesn't seem to work

Comment: Works for me: https://github.com/GTmAster/BindDemo. Please check your host setup, maybe something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Core you're using but you have to configure the section first and then use the resolver to get the instance of the service:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyClass,MyClass>();

services.Configure<MyClass>(section);
services.AddScoped(resolver =>
{
  return resolver.GetServices<IOptions<MyClass>>().Value;

}
```